# Running Composer on guest VM with Vagrant and rsync only keeps

Tags: vagrant, composer-php, rsync

I searched about this topic and could not find anything so here I go with my question: I have Linux running in Vagrant as guest, Windows as host; I shared folders with rsync to speed up development with Rails (using NFS or SMB is extremely slow); some of my PHP dependencies get installed with Composer within my project, so when I run Composer via SSH from the guest it downloads and installs them, however, when I restart my VM I lost the dependencies downloaded and need to start over.

So is there anything I could do to run Composer remote or locally, and not loose my changes? so far I've tried changing the sync type to SMB, run Composer, and then go back to rsync, however, I need to switch on and off and I'd like something more automated...

Thank you for your help!

Carlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html):

> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

So this is intentional: If you don't get the result of ANY changes (not just Composer) out of the vagrant machine onto your copy on Windows, it will always get lost inside the VM.

Use SMB or shared folders and bear the performance penalty. Or try and get a NFS server for Windows and install the files inside the VM via NFS.